# Why did the author use "muttering" instead of "mutters" in this sentence?

Tags: gerunds, relative-clauses, participles, compound-adjectives

"He wanders away from the group, muttering something about fingers and toes." - The hunger game, Mockingjay.

And can you give me the name of this grammar structure? Is it short form of relative clause?

Comment: Present participle ("muttering") modifying the subject ("He").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this sentence, *muttering* is a present participle (verb form) in a phrase that serves as an adjective modifying *He*. It could have been structured

> *He, muttering something about fingers and toes, wanders away from the group.*

*Muttering* takes an object, *something*, which is further modified by the adjectival prepositional phrase *about fingers and toes*.

The verb form *mutters* is the third person present tense form, and would only be used in a clause, which would require a subject. It could have been used as follows

> *He wanders away from the group, [while he] mutters something about fingers and toes.*

With the conjunction (while) and subject (he) missing, the sentence has a bit of a run-on quality, which is not unusual in literature. In fact, including the full structure would sound a bit stilted.